# Common Lisp: unable to get the uncompress function in Paul Graham's book working

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Lisp newbie here.

I am reading Paul Graham's book, ANSI Common Lisp.

On page 38 is an `uncompress` function. It takes a list of pairs, where the first item in the pair is a number to indicate how many of the second item there should be. For example, uncompressing this:

```
((3 a) (2 b) c)
```

should produce this:

```
(A A A B B C)
```

I typed the `uncompress` function into a Lisp interpreter (GCL-2.6.2-ANSI) and then tested it like this:

```
(uncompress '((3 A) B (2 C) (5 D)))
```

That produced this error message:

```
Error in IF [or a callee]: Too many arguments.

Fast links are on: do (use-fast-links nil) for debugging
Broken at IF.  Type :H for Help.
 1 (Abort) Return to top level.
```

Below is the `uncompress` function. I think that I faithfully typed what was written in the book. I have tested each piece and each piece seems to work correctly. Truthfully, I'm stuck. I don't know what's causing the error. I'd appreciate your help.

```
(defun uncompress (lst)
   (if (null lst)
       nil
       (let (elt (car lst))
            (rest (uncompress (cdr lst))))
        (if (consp elt)
            (append (apply #'list-of elt)
                    rest)
            (cons elt rest))))

(defun list-of (n elt)
   (if (zerop n)
       nil
       (cons elt (list-of (- n 1) elt))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the most typical common lisp syntax error: incorrect use of parentheses!

Here is the correct version:

```
(defun uncompress (lst)
  (if (null lst)
      nil
      (let ((elt (car lst))
            (rest (uncompress (cdr lst))))
        (if (consp elt)
            (append (apply #'list-of elt)
                    rest)
            (cons elt rest)))))
```

Since these kind of errors are so common when no specialized editor is used, I advise you to use an editor like Emacs or Vim to edit your programs.

Comment: No, you have too few parens around the variable bindings in the `let`. This is not Clojure. :-)

Comment: Ah! I see the missing left paren. Thank you! It is now working perfectly. BTW, I am really liking Lisp; such a beautiful language.

Answer (score 7):

If you use editor indentation tools, the code looks like this:

```
(defun uncompress (lst)
  (if (null lst)
      nil
    (let (elt (car lst))
      (rest (uncompress (cdr lst))))
    (if (consp elt)
        (append (apply #'list-of elt)
                rest)
      (cons elt rest))))
```

That would have made it easier to spot this error. Syntactically it is wrong, since the `IF` does not take more than three forms.

```
(defun uncompress (lst)
  (if (null lst)   ; the IF has four subforms, one too many
      nil
    (let (elt (car lst))  ;<- variables ELT and CAR? Makes no sense
      (rest (uncompress (cdr lst))))   ; <- not using the result?
    (if (consp elt)    ; <- fourth form in IF? Does not make sense.
        (append (apply #'list-of elt)
                rest)
      (cons elt rest))))
```

In Common Lisp both `IF` and `LET` are *special operators* with built-in syntax.

In Lisp the syntax for `LET` usually is:

```
let ({var | (var [init-form])}*) form* => result*
```

In Common Lisp it is possible to add declarations on top of the body forms of the `LET`:

```
let ({var | (var [init-form])}*) declaration* form* => result*
```

The syntax for `IF` in Common Lisp is:

```
if test-form then-form [else-form] => result*
```

**Indentation**

Generally it is not a good idea to manually indent Lisp code. Let the editor or IDE do it. Make sure that all code is properly indented.

If you have a syntax problem: first re-indent the expression -> this makes sure that the code is properly indented and then makes finding problems easier. Next compile the code and read the compiler error message. Common Lisp has great compilers and some have quite good error reporting.

**The code**

The code is not great anyway: it uses recursion where higher-order functions exist or a LOOP would be better

This version got both: the higher-order `MAPCAN` and a `LOOP`:

```
(defun uncompress (list)
  (mapcan #'expand-item list))

(defun expand-item (item)
  (typecase item
    (atom (list item))
    (cons (destructuring-bind (n element) item
              (loop repeat n collect element)))))
```

Comment: @RogerCostello See also [`mappend`](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html#Conses) from [Alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/).

Comment: @coredump: MAPCAN is fine here, because the list are freshly consed and can be linked nicely. ;-)